Gaussian free fields, measures on Banach spaces, and formal Lebesgue densities
I've seen this topic discussed often, but I see conflicting answers. Let's say, for $\phi \in X$, where $X$ is a Banach space, we define:
$$
\tag{1}
\label{*}
p(\phi) \propto \exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2}\langle \phi, S^{-1}\phi\rangle\right\},
$$
where $S$ is a symmetric, positive-definite, trace-class operator on $X$. Then the Gaussian measure $\mu \sim \mathcal{N}(0,S)$ is well-defined on $X$. In the ideal world, we would then like to view $p(\phi)$ as the `probability density' of $\mu$, which of course is problematic because the Lebesgue measure does not exist on $X$.
This is related somewhat to path integrals encountered in physics, where integrals of the type
$$
\tag{2}
\label{**}
\frac{1}{Z} \int_{X} \mathcal{D}\phi\:\exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2}\langle \phi, S^{-1}\phi\rangle\right\} 
$$
are used frequently. This is like the Euclidean path integral of quantum field theory. But, I am not interested in defining $S$ so that $\langle \phi, S^{-1}\phi\rangle$ becomes the action. I am interested in more general operators which give rise to well-defined Gaussian measures on Banach spaces, e.g. fractional Laplacians $S = \Delta^{-\alpha}$, where $\alpha$ satisfies some constraints so that $\text{tr}(\Delta^{-\alpha}) < \infty$.
Now, this is where I have seen some conflicting reports. In some cases, I have seen people claim that (\ref{*}) given above can be rigorously connected to $\mu$ using the theory of Gaussian free fields. However, these arguments usually only concern the classical Wiener measure, and not more general Gaussian meausures. Elsewhere, I see the opinion that it is not possible to make this rigorous and we can only treat $p(\phi)$ as a formal Lebsegue density to gain some insights and that it does not lead to a well-defined measure.
My question is this: is it actually possible to make this rigorous? That is, we would like to say (\ref{*}) can be rigorously interpreted as the Gaussian measure $\mu \sim \mathcal{N}(0,S)$ and (\ref{**}) is its expectation (assuming $Z$ normalizes the measure of course). Are there any references that demonstrate how to do this? Or is it actually not possible as others claim?
